# angular + spring boot war - 403 on refresh

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a war with spring boot and angular as single unit.
This works fine on first go but when I refresh page it shows 403 error.

Steps I used to create war:

1. angular build - ng build --prod --base-href=/ui/ --deploy-url=/ui/
2. I take out the content of dist and paste it in static folder of my spring boot application/
3. Spring security config has code:

   ```
   @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ui/**");
    //super.configure(web);
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/","/api/hello/**","/api/login").permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and().sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
   ```

   }
4. final step is to create an endpoint that will load index.html

   ```
   @GetMapping("/")
      public String loadUI() {
      return "forward:/ui/index.html";
   }
   ```

Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: I also have the same issue with react, any solution ?

Comment: @Hitesh Kumar As angular is single page app, there is no way to fix this. I had to separate both UI and service code and deploy them seperately.

Comment: Thank you @Payal I am trying this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69105081/browser-refresh-not-working-spring-boot-react any idea