# Browser refresh not working, spring boot + React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

When we click on browser refresh it will return 403.
I am trying to fix by using WebMvcConfigurer.addViewControllers().
We are using React and changing the url. for e.g.

> In browser - http://localhost:8080/app/dashoboard.  Actual call -
> http://localhost:8080/app/getDashboard

My code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String FORWARDINDEX = "forward:/index.html";
    private static final String FORWARDASHBOARD = "/getDashboard";
    
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // Map "/"
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(FORWARDINDEX);
        registry.addViewController("/dashboard").setViewName(FORWARDASHBOARD);

        registry.addViewController("/{x:[\\w\\-]+}").setViewName(FORWARDINDEX);
        
        registry.addViewController("/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/**/{y:[\\w\\-]+}").setViewName(FORWARDINDEX);
    }
```

In the above code "/" is working fine but "/dashboard" is not.
We are using spring boot 2.4 and jwt.
Any solution is welcome. We can also try with react.

Comment: I also tried  "forward:/getDashboard"; and no luck

Comment: looks like token issue on refresh.